# What is modifying the CREATE date of my files?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, date-modified

A fairly advanced Windows user here (operating at 3rd Line/TA level for 15 years).

Today is 16th June 2016...

I just browsed through a 100GB of photos within my local Pictures folder collected over the last 20 years or so. I noticed that every single file has had it's CREATED (not modified) time stamp changed to 9th June 2015 (with time between 0630-0650).  Note: 2015, not 2016! The time stamps were all correct last time I checked them (about 5 weeks ago). I know they were correct because I have a Robocopy script which mirrors the pictures to a network share and tells me if a file is detected as older/newer or missing, so I have a good handle on things in that respect.

The time stamp is totally made up. It reflects a date/time in the past (over a year old) that has no correlation with anything that I know of. This seems to be the work of something in the background that is totally ruining good old convention by playing around with and modifying time stamps as per it's liking. Quite frankly, it's bad manners and something new to Windows 8.1/10. I know some third party software changes the modified time stamp without asking (also bad manners) but this seems like a Windows process as I have no third party image processing tools on my PC (and it has affected only picture files).

Any ideas? Anyone experienced the same?